# How to test if content section is provided in RenderSection in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it was possible to test for the existence of a supplied content section when using the RenderSection helper in ASP.NET MVC 3?

For example:

```
@RenderSection("RightCrumbContentArea", required: false)
```

If the above isn't supplied, I wish to generate some other content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible as far as I know.

Try the following code :

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("RightCrumbContentArea")) { 

    @RenderSection("RightCrumbContentArea")

} else { 

    <span>poo</span>
}
```